# Проблемы с версткой

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Проблемы с версткой, при определенных условиях верстка ломается и вот как это выглядит:

[image: проблемы с версткой]

Вот html разметка:

```
<div id="map_details">
<br><br>
<a href="build.php?id=39"><img src="img/x.gif" class="def2" alt="Собственные прибывающие войска" title="Собственные прибывающие войска"></a>
<span class="d2">»</span>
    <div class="mov"><span class="d2">1&nbsp;Приб.</span></div><div class="dur_r">in&nbsp;<span id="timer1">0:08:52</span>&nbsp;ч.</div></div>
```

---

А вот как должно быть правильно:

[image: правильная верстка]

Как исправить ошибку? Как исправить верстку? Что для этого нужно? Какой CSS нужно использовать, что бы добиться такого результата как на второй картинке?

Comment: До тех пор, пока нет кода в студии, рекомендовать будут вырезать ту "глючную" часть фотошопом и приклеить куда надо. Это потому что реализация того, что на вашем скрине, возможна тысячами способов кода. А чтобы порекомендовать что-либо по коду, необходимо знать тот код, с помощью которого у вас реализовано.

Comment: Какие CSS стили нужно применить к этой HTML разметке, чтобы получить результат как на второй картинке?

Answer (score 4):

Засуньте все эти кружочки в один отдельный блок, задайте ему ширину и примените стиль:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Для блоков можете применить

```
float: left/right;
```

Ну и

```
min-width
```